# How to automatically focus to keyboard React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, autofocus

I have a problem with autoFocus for textInput in React Native. I have two screen when i touch to button in **screen A** it navigate to **screen B** and i have a **textInput** in **screen B**. I want auto focus to this textInput when i navigate to **screen B**

This is my code but it's not working, i see the keyboard for a second and it disappear.

```
<TextInput
   placeholder="Search"
   style={styles.searchBar}
   autoFocus={true}
   value={text}
   onChangeText={changeText}
 />
```

I think is not working autoFocus with navigation stack and after i tried with **ref** but i couldn't be succesfull again.

```
const inputRef = useRef(null);
const onFocusHandler = () => {
       inputRef.current.focus();
}
useEffect(() => {
       onFocusHandler();
}, []);
```

TextInput with ref

```
<TextInput
    placeholder="Search"
    style={styles.searchBar}
    ref={inputRef}
    value={text}
    onChangeText={changeText}
/>
```

Comment: Try to give some timeout for `onFocusHandler`

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked! But i didn't get it why it is not working working without timeout ?

Comment: because in `useEffect` the `inputRef` is not assigned yet, or you should use `onLayout` callback to set focus as well